# Transpose matrix ada

Tags: matrix, ada, transpose

How can I transpose matrix in ADA?. I´ve tried:

```
procedure transpose(A: in out matrix)  is
      B : matrix(1..A'Last(2),1..A'Last(1));
   begin
      for i in A'Range(1) loop
         for j in A'Range(2) loop
            B(j,i):= A(i,j);
         end loop;
      end loop;
      A := B;
   end transpose;
```

but it doesn´t work when A isn´t a square Matrix. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If A is a MxN matrix then make sure to allocate B as a NxM matrix.

Comment: if A is MxN then B is NxM, but I can´t  do A :=B because they have diferent dimensions.

Comment: You can’t do `A := B;` because `A` is already constrained as NxM and that constraint can’t be changed.

Comment: If you want `A` to be a matrix whose size can change, you can't simply declare it as an array, because array dimensions are computed when the object is created and can't be changed after that.  There are a number of ways to accomplish it in Ada, but nothing really simple.  You can make `A` an `access` to an array, but that means memory will leak whenever you reassign it to a new access, so you have to deal with allocation issues (`Adjust` and `Finalize` can help with that).  You can declare a record type with discriminants with defaults, where the record has an array component.

Answer (score 9):

As a procedure this can never work for non-square matrices because the output is a different constrained type from the input. However you can *return* `B` from a suitable function.

```
   function transpose(A: in matrix) return matrix  is
      B : matrix(A'Range(2),A'Range(1));
   begin
      for i in A'Range(1) loop
         for j in A'Range(2) loop
            B(j,i):= A(i,j);
         end loop;
      end loop;
      return B;
   end transpose;
```

The easiest way to create a matrix of the right constrained type for the result is a declare block:

```
declare
   Transposed : Matrix := Transpose(A);
begin
   -- operations on the transposed matrix
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose a matrix by creating a record like:

```
type Matrix_Type is record
     Data        : array (1..MAX_SIZE, 1..MAX_SIZE) of Float;
     Last_Row    : Positive range 1 .. MAX_SIZE;
     Last_Column : Positive range 1 .. MAX_SIZE;
end record;
```

This record can support matrices of any m by n size up to n,m <= MAX_SIZE

Your procedure becomes:

```
 procedure transpose(A: in out Matrix_Type) is
      B : Matrix_Type;
   begin
      for i in 1..A.Last_Row loop
         for j in 1..A.Last_Column loop
            B(j,i):= A(i,j);
         end loop;
      end loop;
      B.Last_Column := A.Last_Row;
      B.Last_Row := A.Last_Column;
      A := B;
   end transpose;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of is to use the Fortran convention on an intermediate array-type. (This is because Fortran convention is column-major while in Ada, it is row-major.)

```ada
 Function Transpose(M : Matrix) return Matrix is
    subtype Constrained is Matrix(M'Range(2), M'Range(1));
    Type Xposed is new Matrix with Convention => Fortran;
    Temp   : Xposed := Xposed(M);
    Result : Constrained with Import, Address => Temp'Address; --'
 begin
    Return Result;
 end Transpose;
```